# Convert array of varying sized arrays to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, root, awkward-array

I am working with a root file (array of arrays). When I load the array into python, I get an awkward array since this is an array of arrays of varying sizes. I would like to learn how to convert this to a numpy array of arrays of the same size, by populating empty elements with NaNs. How can I convert an awkward array of varying size to a numpy array?

Comment: can you show some example of your input and your desired output?

Comment: There are various ways of 'padding' arrays.  But it could help if you give us a sense of the array shapes (and dtype). `np.nan` is a float.  Padding a bunch of 1d arrays will be different from 2d or more.  A search on '[numpy] padding' should turn up a lot of SO answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have an array of variable-length lists `a`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> a = ak.Array([[0, 1, 2], [], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> a
<Array [[0, 1, 2], [], ... [5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] type='5 * var * int64'>
```

The function that makes all lists have the same size is [ak.pad_none](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.pad_none.html). But first, we need a size to pad it to. We can get the length of each list with [ak.num](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.num.html) and then take the [np.max](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) of that.

```py
>>> ak.num(a)
<Array [3, 0, 2, 1, 4] type='5 * int64'>
>>> desired_length = np.max(ak.num(a))
>>> desired_length
4
```

Now we can pad it and convert that into a NumPy array (because it now has rectangular shape).

```py
>>> ak.pad_none(a, desired_length)
<Array [[0, 1, 2, None], ... [6, 7, 8, 9]] type='5 * var * ?int64'>
>>> ak.to_numpy(ak.pad_none(a, desired_length))
masked_array(
  data=[[0, 1, 2, --],
        [--, --, --, --],
        [3, 4, --, --],
        [5, --, --, --],
        [6, 7, 8, 9]],
  mask=[[False, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

The missing values (`None`) are converted into a NumPy masked array. If you want a plain NumPy array, you can [ak.fill_none](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.fill_none.html) to give them a replacement value.

```py
>>> ak.to_numpy(ak.fill_none(ak.pad_none(a, desired_length), 999))
array([[  0,   1,   2, 999],
       [999, 999, 999, 999],
       [  3,   4, 999, 999],
       [  5, 999, 999, 999],
       [  6,   7,   8,   9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and implement it accordingly:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
c = max(len(a),len(b))

for i in range(len(a),c):
   a.append(None)
for i in range(len(b),c):
   b.append(None)
```

Result would be as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
b = [1, 2, 3, None, None]
```